# Not all files are listed / shown in FTP (Dedicated Server)

Tags: wordpress, ftp, plesk, filezilla

I just inherited a Wordpress site that a client had half-developed by another web developer.

The site is hosted on a Strato dedicated Server and has got a Plesk installed on it.

I just made an ftp user to get ftp access to the site. Up till here, everything is fine and correct.

The problem is that not all directories and files are shown in the ftp (FileZilla). I know that there are more files, because I can see them in the web file manager.

I thought it was a permissions problem, but I have checked all the permissions and they are all correct.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Once on [su], please include more information: Try any other FTP client and include results. Include raw FTP directory listing and perhaps a screenshot from the Plesk.

Comment: Just moved the question to Super User. Hope there they can help me...

Comment: [Answered copy](http://superuser.com/q/867647/213663) on [su].

Answer (score 5):

1. Open FileZilla FTP client.
2. From the Menu bar choose Server
3. Select Force Showing Hidden Files which should be the last option.

You should now be able to see all files including 'hidden files' within the FTP remote window.
[image: Force showing hidden files]

[Source](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Web-Hosting/Files-and-FTP/accessing-hidden-files-via-ftp-filezilla-4162/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I did as you told me, but didn't work... :(

Comment: I just call, and they told me, dedicated servers don't have support at all... not a great client service... (Strato Spain)

Comment: Then you'll need to find yourself a plesk/server expert who can find out the reason. I would recommend following what the others have said above in the comments and ask in Super User

Answer (score 3):

It's a pretty late reply, but I hope it can help someone out there.

1 - Open "Filezilla"
2 - Click "Site Manager"
3 - See "Protocol" there, click the drop down and select "SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol"

Now connect and everything should be there!

Comment: Any idea __why__ this works?  In my case, some directories listed fine under standard FTP, but others didn't.  Using SSH (SFTP) connection all directories seem to list fine.

Comment: @cartbeforehorse I think it's to do with Firewall settings.  See: https://serverfault.com/questions/421161/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-work-with-passive-mode . SFTP keeps to port 22 I think, while FTP uses all sorts of ports, some of which may be blocked, others of which may not be (dependent on your environment).